# automated build of python eggs

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, setup.py, distribute

I have a directory containing `N` subdirectories each of which contains `setup.py` file. I want to write a python script that iterates through all subdirectories, issues `python setup.py bdist_egg --dist-dir=somedir`, and finally removes `build` and `*.egg-info` from each subdirectory and I have two questions:

1. Can I invoke `bdist_egg` without using `os.system`? Some python interface would be nicer.
2. Can I tell `bdist_egg` not to generate `build` and `*.egg-info` or is there any complementary command for `setup.py` that cleans this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Fabric is the right way!

Answer (score 0):

1. I would use `subprocess`. I believe `setup.py` command line arguments should be your interface.
2. Check `setup.py clean --all`